# perl projects not running eclipse

Tags: eclipse, epic, ubuntu-12.04

I am using Ubuntu 12.04. I have installed epic on my Eclipse as a plugin (the latest 0.6 version).

Now the installation seems to be fine. But whenever I try and run the project using the run button at the top, it does not run. Rather I get a message saying "The selection cannot be launched".

I have done the same thing in windows and the projects runs nicely without any problems.

Also I am not able to see any syntax highlighting in my Ubuntu Eclipse. I am already in the Perl perspective.

What could be going wrong.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With regards to the run button:
1. Try to run the script without the run button, but instead select the script, right click, run as, run local.
2. Try to set your "Run Configurations". Click the down arrow immediately right of the green run arrow. Select "Run Configurations". Select "Perl Local" and then right click to bring up "New".  
Under the "Main" tab set your project and relative script location.
Under other tabs fill in any parameters, arguments, etc.
Save then hit the green button to test.